# OpenGL 3D texture "shine through"

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

For testing purposes I want to display the first slice of a 3D texture. However it seems that the other slices are also displayed.

My vertex shader:

```
#version 130

attribute vec4 position;

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    texcoord = position.xy * vec2(0.5) + vec2(0.5);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 130

uniform sampler3D textures[1];

varying vec2 texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture3D(textures[0], vec3(texcoord.x, texcoord.y, 0));
}
```

I bind the texture from my C++ code using

```
     glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D,0,GL_LUMINANCE,rows-1,cols-1,dep-  1,0,GL_RED,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, vol.data());
```

[image]

This is how it looks; the whole head should not be visible, only the upper portion of it.

Comment: It seems much more likely that there's a problem with the data loading, or the data itself, so that the first slice actually contains the data you are seeing. For example, if you're reading a DICOM dataset, there are often reference slices in the same directory, which are not part of the 3D dataset. I can't picture how content you are not rendering would just magically appear.

Comment: BTW, why are you subtracting 1 from the `rows`, `cols` and `dep` values in the `glTexImage3D()` call? Are those values really 1 more than the actual size of the dataset?

Comment: Yes, these values are used to extract the data from a raw file and the range is exclusive, where in OpenGL they apparently are inclusive (if I omit the -1 the whole dataset is shifted). I also noticed that when picking a slice (for example 0.5) the slice is displayed correctly. The error occurs only for 0 and 1.

Comment: What values do you use for the texture wrap modes? If they are `GL_REPEAT` with linear filtering, texture coordinate 0.0 will be half of the first slice and half of the last slice.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Either choosing nearest neighbour filtering or clamping the R-axis works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use linear filtering (value `GL_LINEAR` for the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` and/or `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` texture parameters), the value of your samples will generally be determined by the two slices closest to your 3rd texture coordinate.

If the size of your 3D texture in the 3rd dimension is `d`, the position of the first slice in texture coordinate space is `0.5 / d`. This is easiest to understand if you picture each slice having a certain thickness in texture coordinate space. Since you have `d` slices, and the texture coordinate range is `[0.0, 1.0]`, each slice has thickness `1.0 / d`. Therefore, the first slice extends from `0.0` to `1.0 / d`, and its center is at `0.5 / d`.

When you use `0.0` for the 3rd texture coordinate, this is not the center of the first slice, and linear sampling comes into play. Since `0.0` is at the edge of the texture, the wrap modes become critical. The default wrap mode is `GL_REPEAT`, meaning that sampling at the edges acts as if the texture was repeated. With this setting, the neighbor of the first slice is the last slice, and texture coordinate `0.0` is exactly in the middle between the first slice and the last slice.

The consequence is that linear sampling with texture coordinate `0.0` will give you the average of the first slice and the last slice.

While `GL_REPEAT` is the default for the wrap modes, it is rarely what you want, unless your texture really contains a repeating pattern. It's certainly not the right setting in this case. What you need here is:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```