# Are texture coordinate range ends at the outer edges of edge texels?

Tags: opengl, textures

From my debugging, I've found that with a 1D texture of 128 pixels in length I have to clamp my `s` coordinate passed to `texture1D` in GLSL fragment shader not to the range `[0,1]`, but to something like `[0,1-1./257]` (increase `257->258` gives the artifact back; the number obtained by bisection to `0.99610897`). Otherwise I have repetitions of the values obtained at `s==0`.

This, of course, doesn't happen when I set texture parameter `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` instead of the default `GL_REPEAT`.

I'm coming to a conclusion that the ends of texture coordinate range are not at the centers of edge texels, but at the outer edges of them.

It would then make sense that if I set `GL_TEXTURE_*_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST` (in `GL_REPEAT` mode), it works as if the sampling looks at the texels at right of the specified `s`, while for `GL_LINEAR` filter it takes average of left and right texels for `s==1`.

Is my conclusion correct? Are the ends of texture coordinate range at the outer edges of the texels, not at their centers?

Comment: Yes. That's the only way that really makes sense. Since [0, 1] covers the entire range of texels, s=1 must be the right edge of the rightmost texel. While not the same question, the explanation would be very similar to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810822/opengl-3d-texture-shine-through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm coming to a conclusion that the ends of texture coordinate range are not at the centers of edge texels, but at the outer edges of them.

Correct.